# Find $\alpha$ from the equations below.

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, numerical-optimization

I need to find $\alpha$ from the equations in below.

Having the following constants: $C$, $K$, $N_k (1\le k \le K)$ and $\lambda_{k,i}(1\le k \le K, 1 \le i \le N_k)$.

What would be $\alpha$ if:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N_k}(1-e^{\large{-\lambda_{k,i}\tau_k}})=C_k \quad (1\le k \le K) \quad [1]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{K} C_k= C \quad [2]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{ \sum_{i=1}^{N_k} \lambda_{k,i}e^{\large{-\lambda_{k,i}}\tau_k}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_k}\lambda_{k,i}^{2}e^{\large{-\lambda_{k,i} \tau_k}} = \alpha \quad (1\le k \le K)\quad [3]
\end{equation}

---

**EDIT:**  I've added my efforts and progress towards an answer below.

from [1], we can say that $\tau_k$ is a function of $C_k$. So, we can rewrite then [1] and [3] as follows respectively:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N_k}(1-e^{-\lambda_{k,i}\tau_k(C_k)})=C_k \quad [4]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{ \sum_{i=1}^{N_k} \lambda_{k,i}e^{-\lambda_{k,i}\tau_k(C_k)}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_k}\lambda_{k,i}^{2}e^{-\lambda_{k,i} \tau_k(C_k)} = \alpha \quad [5]
\end{equation}

Assuming:

\begin{equation}
f_k(C_k) = \frac{1}{ \sum_{i=1}^{N_k} \lambda_{k,i}e^{-\lambda_{k,i}\tau_k(C_k)}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_k}\lambda_{k,i}^{2}e^{-\lambda_{k,i} \tau_k(C_k)}  \quad [6]
\end{equation}

[5] could be rewritten as follows:

\begin{equation}
f_k(C_k) = \alpha \quad [7]
\end{equation}

From [7], we can obtain:

\begin{equation}
C_k = {f_k}^{-1}(\alpha) \quad [8]
\end{equation}

using [8] in [2] results in the following:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=1}^{K}{f_k}^{-1}(\alpha)=C \quad [9]
\end{equation}

So, if we can obtain ${f_k}^{-1}(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ can be computed by solving the fixed-point equation through [9].

However, I don't know how I can obtain ${f_k}^{-1}(\alpha)$ !! Could you please help with a suggestion as to how I can finish?

Comment: What have you considered?  Please add your own efforts, with details as to where, specifically you are stuck in that process (and "I'm clueless", or "I don't know where to start" don't count!)

Comment: In questions like this, where the exponents require enlargement in order to see them clearly, use, e.g. $$\exp\left(-\lambda_{k, i}\tau_k\right)$$ instead of $e^{-\lambda_{k,i}\tau_k}$  See the difference?  In your post, I enlarged the exponents for you, in an attempt to render it readable.  But that should be your concern:  "How can I express my question so that users can read it clearly withouht squinting, and/or without a magnifying glass"?

Comment: @amWhy thanks for your notes. I am gonna apply your comments. I also mentioned my concern in my answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts.  It'd be best to add those efforts in your origninal post, "Edit:  ... " after the current question ends.

Comment: I think that the asker has responded very well, and in good faith, to requests in the comments, by using that feedback to improve the question.  Could the downvoter explain the most recent downvote, which occurred ***after*** the asker's edit to include his/her work?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342708/optimisation-problem-non-linear/2342709#2342709). This question was part of a question posted in the mentioned link.